# stm32l476v TIM15 CH2 PWM not working from cubeMx

Tags: c, stm32, freertos, pwm

I'm trying to start a STM32L576VGT with FreeRTOS.

I have a led blinking from a task and now I'm trying to set a PWM on, freq and duty is not important now, is a "hello world pwm".

All is done using CubeMx, and I'm been unable to make it work.

tim.c generated with CubeMx for TIM15

```
/* TIM15 init function */
void MX_TIM15_Init(void)
{
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig;

  htim15.Instance = TIM15;
  htim15.Init.Prescaler = 47999;
  htim15.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim15.Init.Period = 200;
  htim15.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim15.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim15.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim15) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim15, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim15, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim15);



}

void HAL_TIM_PWM_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* tim_pwmHandle)
{
  if(tim_pwmHandle->Instance==TIM15)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_MspInit 0 */
  /* USER CODE END TIM15_MspInit 0 */
    /* TIM15 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM15_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_MspInit 1 */
  /* USER CODE END TIM15_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* timHandle)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(timHandle->Instance==TIM15)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_MspPostInit 0 */
  /* USER CODE END TIM15_MspPostInit 0 */
    /**TIM15 GPIO Configuration    
    PB15     ------> TIM15_CH2
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_15;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_TIM15;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM15_MspPostInit 1 */
  /* USER CODE END TIM15_MspPostInit 1 */
  }
}
```

main in main.c

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  /* USER CODE END 1 */
  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  /* USER CODE END Init */
  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  /* USER CODE END SysInit */
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_QUADSPI_Init();
  MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_TIM15_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
//  DISP_diplay_init();
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim15,TIM_CHANNEL_2);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
  /* Call init function for freertos objects (in freertos.c) */
  MX_FREERTOS_Init();
  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();
  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

I'm using TIM15 because the PCB is already done and it is the one is connected to the output i want to control.

Thanks,
Guillermo

Comment: And what have you done so far to find where the problem is. Connect the debugger stop it and see the timer 15 registers

Comment: Ps. In this hundred lines of the code do you enable it somewhere

Comment: the debbugin is what I'm doing now, and yes in main you can see the MX_TIM15_Init(); and HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim15,TIM_CHANNEL_2);

Comment: And what does your debugger say about the values of the uC registers? Are they as expected?

Comment: Have you tried with different values on `sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;`?

Comment: JMA you where right, I complete forgot to change the Puls value, if you put this as an answer I will mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @taquionbcn Moltes Gràcies ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with different values on `sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;`?